# Fire JS after functions in loop when other function is complete

Tags: javascript

I have this function `function copy(){ // do some stuff }`, this function is triggerd by

```
<input type="text" id="calc_inkoop_std" name="calc_inkoop_std" value="" onkeyup="copy()">
```

After this function I need to have another function triggerd, but since this is an loop I can't just simple use `validate(selectVeld, nr)`

How can I run through all lines of `function validate(selectVeld, nr) { // do some stuff }`

Complete JS

```
    function copy()
    {
        // Kopieer materiaalkosten
        var i, totaal = 0;
        var elems = document.getElementsByName('calc_inkoop_std_copy[]');
        var l = elems.length;
        for(i=0; i<l; i++)
        {
            elems[i].value = document.getElementById('calc_inkoop_std').value;
        }

        validate();
    }

    function validate(selectVeld, nr)
    {
        // Materiaalkosten
        if(document.getElementById('calc_inkoop['+nr+'][]').value > 0)
        {
            document.getElementById('calc_materiaalkost['+nr+'][]').value  = ((document.getElementById('calc_gewicht_stk['+nr+'][]').value * (document.getElementById('calc_inkoop['+nr+'][]').value / 1000)) * ((document.getElementById('calc_afval_perc['+nr+'][]').value / 100) + (1 * 1))).toFixed( 2 );
        }
        else
        {
            document.getElementById('calc_materiaalkost['+nr+'][]').value  = ((document.getElementById('calc_gewicht_stk['+nr+'][]').value * (document.getElementById('calc_inkoop_std_copy['+nr+'][]').value / 1000)) * ((document.getElementById('calc_afval_perc['+nr+'][]').value / 100) + (1 * 1))).toFixed( 2 );
        }
    }
```

The other JS is triggerd in an loop:

```
while($row_table_3 = mysqli_fetch_array($res_table_3)){ $y++;
echo'
      <tr>
        <td>
            <input type="number" id="calc_aantal['.$y.'][]" name="calc_aantal[]" value="" onkeyup="validate(this, '.$y.')">
        </td>
      </tr>';
} echo '
```

If I am using this code only line 5 is updated of `validate`. But `[i]` should be the number of the line?

```
var i, totaal = 0;
var elems = document.getElementsByName('calc_inkoop_std_copy[]');
var l = elems.length;
for(i=0; i<l; i++)
{
    elems[i].value = document.getElementById('calc_inkoop_std').value;

    validate([i], 5);
}
```

Comment: at the end of `copy()`, call `validate()`; or you can check async() or callback()

Comment: As written in the post, I am not able to simply use `validate();`. That gives an error: `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'value' of null`

Comment: so when are you calling `validate()`  ??. can you post the full block

Comment: After `{
  elems[i].value = document.getElementById('calc_inkoop_std').value;
 }`

Comment: can you add this to your question. see we cannot guess where you are going to use functions. Please  update the question to full code :)

Comment: I have added the line of code as requested

Comment: bro you are not passing any params to `validate()`, what does the params do here, what is the actual use of `validate()` here ??

Comment: I have updated my post.

Comment: you can queue those as a microtask wich will run after your stack is cleared and before any makrotask

Comment: Can you walk me trough that @Estradiaz ?

Comment: I think start here https://jakearchibald.com/2015/tasks-microtasks-queues-and-schedules/ and here https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTML_DOM_API/Microtask_guide

Comment: I don't think this solution is suited for my issue @Estradiaz

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my HTML structure `$y` starts at 1 at it's first occurrence.
In the JS loop `i` starts as 0 at it's first occurrence.

Now I have this solution:

```
var i, totaal = 0;
var elems = document.getElementsByName('calc_inkoop_std_copy[]');
var l = elems.length;

var z;
z=0;

for(i=0; i<l; i++)
{
    elems[i].value = document.getElementById('calc_inkoop_std').value;

    z++;
    validate([i], [z]);
}
```